# Typesetting bidirectional breadth first search with Algotype.js

Tags: algorithm, html, breadth-first-search, typesetting

So I have this:

[image: Bidirectional breadth first search using Algotype.js]

And the typesetting code is here:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#step_id1 {
    color: black;
}

#comment_id1 {
    color: black;
}

#step_id2 {
    color: brown;
}

#comment_id2 {
    color: black;
}

#step_id3 {
    color: black;
}

#comment_id3 {
    color: blue;
}

#step_id4 {
    color: brown;
}

#comment_id4 {
    color: blue;
}

#yield_id {
    color: blueviolet;
}

.upper_header_bar {
    border-top: 3px solid #ff2222 !important;
    width: 550px;
}

.lower_header_bar {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black !important; 
    width: 550px;
}

.footer_bar {
    background-color: #ff2222;
    width: 550px; 
    height: 3px;
}
</style>
<script src="Algotype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<alg-algorithm header="Bidirectional-Breadth-First-Search$(s, t)$"
               algorithm-upper-header-class="upper_header_bar"
               algorithm-lower-header-class="lower_header_bar"
               algorithm-footer-class="footer_bar">
    <alg-if condition="$s = t$">
         <alg-return>$\langle s \rangle$</alg-return>
    </alg-if>
    <alg-step>$Q_A \leftarrow \langle s \rangle$</alg-step>
    <alg-step>$Q_B \leftarrow \langle t \rangle$</alg-step>
    <alg-step>$\pi_A \leftarrow  \{ (s \mapsto \Nil) \}$</alg-step>
    <alg-step>$\pi_B \leftarrow  \{ (t \mapsto \Nil) \}$</alg-step>
    <alg-step>$\delta_A \leftarrow \{ (s \mapsto 0) \}$</alg-step>
    <alg-step>$\delta_B \leftarrow \{ (t \mapsto 0) \}$</alg-step>
    <alg-step>$C \leftarrow \infty$</alg-step>
    <alg-step>$\mu \leftarrow \Nil$</alg-step>
    <alg-while condition="$|Q_A| > 0 \; \And \; |Q_B| > 0$">
        <alg-step>$\Delta_A \leftarrow \delta_A($Front$(Q_A))$</alg-step>
        <alg-step>$\Delta_B \leftarrow \delta_B($Front$(Q_B))$</alg-step>
        <alg-if condition="$\mu \neq \Nil \; \And \; C \lt \Delta_A + \Delta_B$">
            <alg-return>Traceback-Path$(\mu, \pi_A, \pi_B)$</alg-return>
        </alg-if>
        <alg-if condition="$|\delta_A| < |\delta_B|$">
            <alg-step>$u \leftarrow $Remove-First$(Q_A)$</alg-step>
            <alg-foreach condition="$v \in $Children$(u)$">
                <alg-if condition="$v\;\Not\;\Mapped\;\In\;\delta_A$">
                    <alg-step>$\delta_A(v) \leftarrow \delta_A(u) + 1$</alg-step>
                    <alg-step>$\pi_A(v) \leftarrow u$</alg-step>
                    <alg-step>Add-Last$(Q_A, v)$</alg-step>
                    <alg-if condition="$v\; \Mapped \; \In \; \delta_B \; \And \; C \gt \delta_A(v) + \delta_B(v)$">
                        <alg-step>$C \leftarrow \delta_A(v) + \delta_B(v)$</alg-step>
                        <alg-step>$\mu \leftarrow v$</alg-step>
                    </alg-if>
                </alg-if>
            </alg-foreach>
        </alg-if>
        <alg-else>
            <alg-step>$u \leftarrow $Remove-First$(Q_B)$</alg-step>
            <alg-foreach condition="$v \in $Parents$(u)$">
                <alg-if condition="$v\;\Not\;\Mapped\;\In\;\delta_B$">
                    <alg-step>$\delta_B(v) \leftarrow \delta_B(u) + 1$</alg-step>
                    <alg-step>$\pi_B(v) \leftarrow u$</alg-step>
                    <alg-step>Add-Last$(Q_B, v)$</alg-step>
                    <alg-if condition="$v\; \Mapped \; \In \; \delta_A \; \And \; C \gt \delta_A(v) + \delta_B(v)$">
                        <alg-step>$C \leftarrow \delta_A(v) + \delta_B(v)$</alg-step>
                        <alg-step>$\mu \leftarrow v$</alg-step>
                    </alg-if>
                </alg-if>
            </alg-foreach>
        </alg-else>
    </alg-while>
    <alg-error>No path between $s$ and $t$.</alg-error> 
</alg-algorithm>
<alg-algorithm header="Traceback-Path$(\mu, \pi_A, \pi_B)$"
               algorithm-upper-header-class="upper_header_bar"
               algorithm-lower-header-class="lower_header_bar"
               algorithm-footer-class="footer_bar">
    <alg-step>$p \leftarrow \langle \rangle$</alg-step> 
    <alg-step>$u \leftarrow \mu$</alg-step>
    <alg-while condition="$u \neq \Nil$">
        <alg-step>Add-First$(p, u)$</alg-step>
        <alg-step>$u \leftarrow \pi_A(u)$</alg-step>
    </alg-while>
    <alg-step>$u \leftarrow \pi_B(u)$</alg-step>
    <alg-while condition="$u \neq \Nil$">
        <alg-step>Add-Last$(p, u)$</alg-step>
        <alg-step>$u \leftarrow \pi_B(u)$</alg-step>
    </alg-while>
    <alg-return>$p$</alg-return>
</alg-alg-algorithm>

</body>
</html>
```

(The `Algotype.js` lives [here](https://github.com/coderodde/Algotype.js).)

Please tell me whatever comes to mind.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:latex] when the norm, here, is to tag latex as [tag:tex]? Also isn't this using just plain TeX at best and MathJax at worst, so I'm not sure it should have either tag.